# Prolog Find Cheapest Price

Tags: prolog

I have following set of facts:

```
flight(kul,syd,495,2205).
flight(jhb,kul,45,321).
flight(pen,kul,55,346).
flight(lgk,kul,65,381).
flight(lgk,pen,35,215).
flight(kul,sin,65,760).
flight(lgk,sin,90,1058).
flight(sin,bki,150,1492).
flight(kul,bki,155,526).
flight(kul,lbu,145,436).
flight(lbu,bki,30,127).
flight(bki,per,340,1835).
flight(kul,per,330,1835).
flight(myy,bki,55,167).
flight(kul,myy,130,511).
flight(lbu,myy,45,108).
flight(sin,per,310,2289).
flight(sin,syd,475,3118).
```

which is `flight(FROM,TO,EST,PRICE).`

now i need to create a rule to find the cheapest fare between two cities. It will mean the world if someone could help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
graph :-
    forall(flight(From,To,_,_), writeln(From -> To)).
```

displays the topology, we can appreciate the graph is acyclic:
[image]

OT: to display edge infos:

```
graph_dist_cost :-
    forall(flight(From,To,Dist,Cost),
           format('~q [label="~w\\n~w"];~n', [From -> To, d=Dist,c=Cost])).
```

now, since it's acyclic, we can state:

```
path(To,To,[]).
path(From,To,[Step|Rest]) :-
    Step = flight(From,ToTemp,_Dist,_Cost),
    call(Step),
    path(ToTemp,To,Rest).
```

and we get:

```
?- path(jhb,myy,P).
P = [flight(jhb, kul, 45, 321), flight(kul, lbu, 145, 436), flight(lbu, myy, 45, 108)] ;
P = [flight(jhb, kul, 45, 321), flight(kul, myy, 130, 511)] ;
false.
```

now, it's easy to get numeric values

```
path_cost(P, C) :-
    aggregate_all(sum(Cost), member(flight(_,_,_,Cost), P), C).

?- path(jhb,myy,P),path_cost(P,C).
P = [flight(jhb, kul, 45, 321), flight(kul, lbu, 145, 436), flight(lbu, myy, 45, 108)],
C = 865 ;
P = [flight(jhb, kul, 45, 321), flight(kul, myy, 130, 511)],
C = 832 ;
false.
```

then, the minimum:

```
path_min_cost(From, To, Min, Path) :-
    aggregate(min(C,P), (path(From,To,P),path_cost(P,C)), min(Min,Path)).

?- path_min_cost(jhb,myy,P,MC).
P = 832,
MC = [flight(jhb, kul, 45, 321), flight(kul, myy, 130, 511)].
```

as you can see, such queries are very simple...

Comment: wow it actually worked.. but I need some explainations on how do u do it. some people suggests that I use setof or bagof as it is more efficient. but anyway, thank you very much sir! I cant believe you went through all this. not to mention the topology.. wow words cant describe how thankful I am.

Comment: Actually, I attempted to keep as simple as possible. Before to worry for performance, and optimizations, see if you can make sense of the way the problem has been **decomposed**. Searching - the broad theme faced in this question, is at heart of Prolog. Arithmetic, that we need for numeric values, it's less developed - so I've shown the most idiomatic code, based on library(aggregate). Internally, library(aggregate) uses setof/3, findall/3 and the like...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the cheapest fare, then the distance field becomes irrelevant. The strategy is to find layover points C where travelling from A to C and then to B is cheaper than going straight from A to B. You can't find the cheapest fare, then, without somehow 'checking' all the possibilities.

You can efficiently do so and find the cheapest fare between two cities A and B by organizing your data into a hash table of hash tables:

1. Iterating through your data, make a list of all the flight from A to SOMEWHERE.
2. For each of those SOMEWHERE's, make a list of all the flights from there to other destinations.
   So on...

After arranging your data accordingly, any lookup of cheapest total PRICE will be in constant time.

Comment: @IzzatAmir please don't show your coding attempts in a comment. It's difficult to read, and it's not easily noticed by others who could help you with your problem. You should edit your original problem and add your coding attempt using proper formatting.